# The only thing she’s done wrong is [show it to me]

Tags: cleft-constructions

> The only thing she’s done wrong is show it to me.
>   (The Silkworm, by Robert Galbraith)
>
> The last thing he wanted to do was rescue her.
>   (The Town, Chuck Hogan)

Both the sentences seem to have non-finite clauses as complements just as pseudo-clefts do (*CGEL,p.1422, What you must do is apply for special leave*.) Can I understand them as pseudo-cleft constructions?.

Comment: Hmm, interesting question. :) -- The meaning seems somewhat similar (related info, somewhat, is *CGEL* page 1423, [32]), that is, if the expression "The last thing" had been "The thing" or "All" instead, then there could be: *"[The thing | All] he wanted to do was rescue her", "He wanted to rescue her", "What he wanted to do was rescue her"* which have similar meanings, or so it seems. But, unfortunately, the expression "The last thing" usually has the opposite meaning, in that he does not want to do that thing ("He most certainly didn't want to rescue her").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most of the cases, pseudo-cleft sentences begin with ***'What-clause'***. This said, the emphasis in such sentences is on the phrase after `What clause + be...`

Some examples are -

> *What you need is a good vehicle.* 
>   *What changed him completely was an autobiography of Mahatma Gandhi.*

Good to note that if you want to refer to a ***person,*** we can say *The person/people* and there *What* is not needed. For instance,

> *The person whom I met was the CEO of the company.*

To answer your question, you *cannot* consider them as pseudo-cleft sentences.